# ipython notebook as a simple webapp?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm interested in whether there's a good way to start the evaluation of a ipython notebook, run it in background, and have a user log in to that specific notebook only when user input is needed (i.e., prompt from `raw_input`).

The specific use case is:
1. Need a set of labeled examples for a supervised classification problem
2. Those examples are generated in real time (basically, the classifier dynamically updates 'uncertain' cases and asks for user input)
3. After N labels are provided, the classifer keeps running

I'd like to be able kick off the process, and require the user to log in to the notebook only for item (2). Users aren't particularly technical, so a web-based front-end that lets them access this specific part of the process without having to actually run the code themselves would be great.

Can the ipython notebook support this by running in background for items (1) and (3), with the user loggen in for only (2)? Or does the entire process need to run as a single logged-in session?